# 20 seconds video to introduce yourself; what things to consider?

Tags: interviewing, new-job, canada, dress-code

After applying for a job, I received an email asking to make a 20 seconds video to introduce myself.

I wonder what information should I put in this very short video?

Is there anything specific they are looking for in that video?

Shall I dress up a suit and tie?

Comment: What kind of job are you applying to? Also, what country are you located?

Comment: data manager in Canada

Comment: Sending a 20 second video of hypnotoad is tempting for these...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before thinking about the video, do this simple exercise: describe yourself in 100 words, then 50, then 30, then 10.
Next, think about the job you are interviewing for, and see how you can tweak your introductions to make them relevant and engaging, mentioning key terms related to your achievements, expertise and qualities.

20 seconds can be very short or very long. Spend some time on this. It will be very useful for future "elevator pitches".

Comment: I'm not sure if this is still a problem, but If you do go for a "business shirt", make sure it's plain; no stripes or check patterns, as these can cause striations in the video.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder what information should I put in this very short video?

You should put information and facts that briefly but concisely describe you.

Things I suggest you include may be your educational background (what you studied, where), your professional interests (past projects or gigs), and also some more personal facts, like what is your preferred name, what are your hobbies, etc..

> Is there anything specific they are looking for in that video?

Can't tell what *their* true intentions are, but most likely (and also judging by what they asked you to do), they are seeking a brief introduction and description about yourself, so they can (perhaps?) get a more realistic look-and-feel on what you are in person.

They may show this to the current team, or to the ones deciding on who gets hired, so they can give feedback on potential candidates.

> Shall I dress up a suite and tie?

You mention this is a Data Manager position, so wearing suite and tie *could* be a bit of an overkill. However, I would not go the other opposite and wear a t-shirt of your favorite sports team...

Perhaps a Polo-like shirt could do the trick (remember, it's a 20 sec video you will probably record with your phone or laptop camera).

This also depends on your country and company culture. I suggest you do some research on how they usually dress on that company, specially people in similar roles, and go for that. Perhaps the way the people that interviewed you dressed could give you some clues.

...and if everything else fails, remember that it's better to be *over-dressed* than *under-dressed*.

Comment: Please read the whole answer where I suggested op to probe and see what's more adequate for their context (if one, say, is applying for a janitor job "business casual" would be out of context). Also, if you have some other suggestions for OP please post an answer for it to be considered

Comment: @Niko1978 I have never seen a proper dress shirt  with a tie as business casual makes you look like a dodgy property developer